# Display another window from one window in PyQt

Tags: button, pyqt

I have created a main window in PyQt which has a button. I wish to use that button to display another window and also the main window should get closed or hidden. I have written the following code, but the main window is not hiding after the button is clicked.

```
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s


#Second window
class Ui_Dialog(QtGui.QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None,   QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        pass

#Main window
class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(309, 148)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 191, 71))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Open Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.showDial)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        pass

    #function to display another form
    def showDial(self):
      Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
      u = Ui_Dialog()
      u.setupUi(Dialog)
      self.close()
      Dialog.exec_()
      #self.hide()
      #self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that in `showDial`, self is the Ui object, not the window itself. Personally, I don't like creating separate objects this way (I assume this is inspired by a GUI designer), but you can store the object itself in setupUi and reference it like this:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(309, 148)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 191, 71))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Open Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(("pushButton"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.showDial)
        self.win = MainWindow

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    #function to display another form
    def showDial(self):
      Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
      u = Ui_Dialog()
      u.setupUi(Dialog)
      self.win.close()
      Dialog.exec_()
      #self.hide()
      #self.close()
```

(also note that you call `app.exec_()` twice)

A simple alternative to your pattern:

```
    MainWindow = Ui_MainWindow()
    MainWindow.setupUi(MainWindow) #note that self and MainWindow are the same
```

and have Ui_MainWindow inherit from QMainWindow instead of QWidget.